# errorObj: unknown Object is of type 'unknown'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await

I am getting the error while using async, await in useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (contentLoader) {
      (async () => {
        try {
          const data = await promise;
          setData(data);
        } catch (errorObj) {
          if (!errorObj?.value) { //here i'm getting --> errorObj: unknown Object is of type 'unknown'.
            setError(errorObj);
            console.log(`loading document error: ${errorObj}`);
          }
        }
      })();
    } else // something else
}, [..])
```

whats wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You're using TypeScript 4.4 or newer with [`use-unknown-catch-variables`] (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#use-unknown-catch-variables) enabled.

The easiest fix, if you don't know the actual type of the error thrown, is to just tell TypeScript that it's `any`, not `unknown`.

```
catch (errorObj) {
```

->

```
catch (errorObj: any) {
```

Comment: tried this as well, got different error --> Catch clause variable cannot have a type annotation.  TS1196